# Removing first n rows from excel sheet

Tags: c#

I have around 200 excel files in a directory and want to remove the first 4 rows from all of them and then merge them, I have a tool for merging and just need to delete first 4 rows.
I've no experience in excel programming. Could you please guide me how I can do it? Your help is highly appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
void DeleteRows(Workbook book, int n)
{           
    foreach (Excel.Worksheet workSheet in book.Sheets)
    {
        Excel.Range range = workSheet.get_Range("A1", "A" + n); 
        Excel.Range row = range.EntireRow;
        row.Delete(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);
    }
}
```